# How to get sheet seqence by sheet name

Tags: google-apps-script

a google-app-script spreadsheet (inputBookObj) have 3 sheets

```
[0] "ABC"
[1] "DEF"
[2] "HIJ"
```

How can I get sequence "1" by sheet name "DEF" without looping all sheets in "inputBookObj"?

I have already tried sheet Class .getId() which do not return the sequence.

```
var startSheetObj = inputBookObj.getSheetByName("DEF");
var startSheetId = startSheetObj.getSheetId();
for (var st_idx = startSheetId; st_idx >= 0; st_idx --) {
```

I expect startSheetId to be 1, but I get 2050320780.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridId is different from sheet index. You can use [`sheet.getIndex()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getIndex()) to get the index of the sheet in parent.

```
var startSheetObj = inputBookObj.getSheetByName("DEF");
var startSheetId = startSheetObj.getIndex();//-1, if you want to start from 0
Logger.log(startSheetId);//logs 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I did read documents but how could I miss the method "getIndex()".

Answer (score 0):

### You can use the method [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets())

Sample:

```
var startSheetObj = inputBookObj.getSheets()[1];
```

Or, you want to loop through all sheets of a spreadsheet:

```
var sheets=inputBookObj.getSheets();
for (var st_idx = sheets.length; st_idx >= 0; st_idx --) {
...
}
```

> As for the sheet Id, it the number at the end of the spreadsheet Url,
>   e.g. `...gid=0` means that the sheet Id is `0`. However, if you insert
>   a second sheet, its id will look something like `...gid=1668900245` -
>   there is no sequential order, unless you create thee sheet with the
>   [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api), where you can specify the id of the new sheet.